# How to get session value into an ASP Parameter tag?

Tags: asp.net

I have following code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [gMeter] SET ... [userId] = @userId ...
```

I need to parametr @userId assign session variable `Session["userId"]`, any ideas? I tried

```
[userId] = <%= Session["userId"]%>
```

But it does not works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this inside your `asp:SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="userId" SessionField="userId" Type="Int32" />
```